# Ubuntu 9.10 Netbook Remix: Screen goes blank on install from USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbook, ubuntu-netbook-remix

I am trying to install Ubuntu Netbook on an iiView A2. I realize this is not necessarily supported according to the Ubuntu documentation, however, one of my friends who has the same netbook was able to accomplish this with no issues.

The computer boots up from the USB just fine, I get to the menu and choose install Ubuntu. I see a cursor flash on the screen for a second and then the Ubuntu logo. Immediately after seeing the Ubuntu logo the screen goes black (or blank) and I get no HDD activity (or any other activity). I have let it set for quite some time but it does not appear to be doing anything.

This same kind of thing happens when I choose Try Ubuntu without installing from the initial menu after boot. **Any suggestions regarding how to install this on the netbook would be greatly appreciated.** It sounds like it may be something to do with the video card. If that's the case any idea how to install from the command line and edit xorg.conf later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before clicking on install goto F4 and choose safe graphics mode then continue to install it worked for me :)  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try a text-mode install.